# ffmpeg video aspect ratio for new Instagram API

Tags: video, ffmpeg

For the new Instagram API videos that are uploaded need to be:

- Between 4:5 and 16:9 (aspect ratio range)
- Between 0.8 and 1.78 (numeric aspect ratio range)

So, for example, an aspect ratio written as 4:5 has a value of 4/5 = 0.8.

Any aspect ratio within is fine. How could I make it so that ffmpeg checks if it's between those ratios and if not, rescales it (using some kind of padding).

I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=sample_aspect_ratio=0.8 video2.mp4
```

This does not seem to be doing anything.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "scale=w=640:h=640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=w=640:h=640:x=(iw-ow)/2:y=(ih-oh/2):color=white" video2.mp4
```

This only scales to 640x640 and adds white padding.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "pad=w=max(ih*4/5\,iw):h=ih:x=(iw-ow)/2:y=(ih-oh/2):color=black,pad=w=iw:h=max(iw*9/16\,ih):x=(iw-ow)/2:y=(ih-oh/2):color=black" video2.mp4`

The first pad will add padding if input DAR is less than 4/5 and not otherwise. The second pad will add padding if input DAR is more than 16/9 and not otherwise.